# To Bring the exact match at very top from Search Results (Apache Solr 5.5)

Tags: solr, full-text-search, search-engine, full-text-indexing

I have a field "description" and I am searching a text against this filed having default Similarity scoring. Say, i have searched for "hello man" and i am getting results like "hello mango", "hello man how you", "hello man10", "hello man", "hello mann". All these are  expected results, but i want to display the exact matches (here it is "hello man") at the very top of partial matches. To get results against typo i am using nGramFilterFactory while indexing and querying and it is the requirement. Only thing i am worried here is the exact match is not coming at the top.

Please suggest how we can do this or what kind of approach i need to go for. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define another field in your `schema.xml` that doesn't do any analysis on your data. The easiest way to do this in your case is probably doing the following:

`<field name="exact_description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />`

`<copyField source="originalColumnName" dest="exact_description" docValues="true" />`

Using the `string` type will keep Solr from tokenizing or doing anything else to your data.

Then, when building your query, you can put something like the following before the rest of your query:

`exact_description:"hello man"^100.0`

Make sure you put a boost (the `^100.0`) of your choice on `exact_description`, so exact matches will be forced to the top of your results.

When you create your new field, make sure you base it off of a field that hasn't had any analysis performed on it. For example, in my schema, I have a field called `exact_match`, which is copied from the following:

`<field name="match" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" omitNorms="true" />`

Now, I could have just used `match` for exact matches in search since `match` is just a string, but for spec reasons I had to create `exact_match` like this:

`<field name="exact_match" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />`

`<copyField source="match" dest="exact_match" docValues="true" />`

Comment: Sorry, Still I couldn't resolve this :(  I am posting  my schema as answer. Please check  and help me where i am wrong

Comment: @Niranjan I added a little more info for you. I would also recommend you delete your answer on this question and edit your question to contain the schema. It will help other people who have this same problem in the future to have all relevant info in the question.

Comment: This one worked. Thanks a lot. Also i have removed my schema from the answer section...

Comment: i have a similar problem but i cannot use String since the data has comma separated values. for the query to work and return results, I had to use textfield. i now need results which match "Hello man" at the top and rest at the bottom.
for me, the score is 1.0 for all the results, so i dont think i can sort on that.